# Xamarin.Forms (iOS) MessagingCenter message from AppDelegate is not delivered

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, messagingcenter

I have next goal: my app receives push notifications (FCM) and I need to handle user manipulations with them in all possible scenarios.

- When I receive foreground push and handle it in **WillPresentNotification** - everything works as expected.
- When I sent app to the background mode (clicking home button) and receive a push, click on that push at Notification Center I have next code in **DidReceiveNotificationResponse** method:

  ```
   MessagingCenter.Send<object, PushNotificationObject>(this, "PushNavigationToRootPage", push);
  ```

So it just sends a message to the RootPage, which is subscribed/unsubscribed as below:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
   base.OnAppearing();
   MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object, PushNotificationObject>(this, "PushNavigationToRootPage");
   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object, PushNotificationObject>(this, "PushNavigationToRootPage", (sender, _push) => { ... });
}
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
   MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<object, PushNotificationObject>(this, "PushNavigationToRootPage");
   base.OnDisappearing();
}
enter code here
```

**It also works! BUT!**

- If I completely close the app (swipe it off from App Switcher) and then click on the received push - it will only Send a message (from the code above), but will never reach code which is placed inside Subscribe of a RootPage.

Any ideas of what is wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you are sending a message BEFORE the RootPage has subscribed, then that message will be lost

Comment: @Jason, how can I avoid that and make my RootPage subscribe before I send?

Comment: I don't know.  I would have to know more about your architecture to suggest anything.  It may be that if the notification is received while the app is dead then you need to use some other mechanism to notify the root page.  Or create some queuing mechanism that will wait until the root page is active

Comment: @Jason you have pointed me to the right direction! The solutions was to revisit some basic architecture things and in the needed moment make a call to create and map views with view models and etc.
Thanks!